# GROUP half of the SELECT columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
SELECT Property.PropertyID, Property.Name, BTAT.Action as Status, BTAT.Total, BTAT.BookingID, DateTimeCreatedRealtime
FROM BookingTotalAuditTrail as BTAT
LEFT JOIN Booking ON Booking.BookingID=BTAT.BookingID
LEFT JOIN PropertyBooking ON BTAT.BookingID=PropertyBooking.BookingID
LEFT JOIN Property ON PropertyBooking.PropertyID=Property.PropertyID
WHERE (PropertyBooking.PropertyID IN(25)) AND (DateTimeCreatedRealTime BETWEEN CAST('2018-02-13 00:00:00' as datetime) AND CAST('2018-02-14 23:59:59' as datetime))
ORDER BY DateTimeCreatedRealtime DESC
```

Returns

```
PropertyID  Name                    Status      Total BookingID DateTimeCreatedRealTime
25          Beach Resort & Villas   Modified    543   747890    2018-02-13 09:56:40
25          Beach Resort & Villas   Modified    499   747890    2018-02-13 09:56:21
25          Beach Resort & Villas   Modified    499   747890    2018-02-13 09:56:19
25          Beach Resort & Villas   New         277   747890    2018-02-13 09:56:09
```

But I want to group rows by BookingID and Status, and use max(DateTimeCreatedRealTime) to grab the oldest row. So the above becomes

```
PropertyID  Name                    Status      Total BookingID DateTimeCreatedRealTime
25          Beach Resort & Villas   Modified    543   747890    2018-02-13 09:56:40
25          Beach Resort & Villas   New         277   747890    2018-02-13 09:56:09
```

I run into issues when applying `SELECT max(DateTimeCreatedRealTime)` and

```
GROUP BY Property.PropertyID, Property.Name, BTAT.Action, BTAT.BookingID
```

> Column 'BookingTotalAuditTrail.Total' is invalid in
>   the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate
>   function or the GROUP BY clause.

The problem being I do not want to group by Total, Duration, and DateTimeCreatedRealTime.

How can I go about this?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest window functions:

```
with t as (
      < your query here >
     )
select t.*
from (select t.*, row_number() over (partition by bookingid, status order by DateTimeCreatedRealTime) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you group by some columns, the other columns need to be wrapped in Aggregate functions - as they will potentially have more than one value per row after the grouping...

So you will have to use MAX() or MIN() or FIRST() or SUM() or something on all the columns not in your grouping, depending on which value you want to see for the group...

If there are two or more rows for a specific ProperyId, Name, Action and BookID combination - which of the values do you want to use for Total Duration and DateTimeCreatedRealTime as there will be more than one?? If you expect them to all be the same - you can just use FIRST() to get the first of the values.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do a separate query or inner query to find the ids of the most recent rows, and then select their fields.

if you are using Postgresql, you can look into using 'DISTINCT ON' to do this in one single query.